# How to get list of all branch names in bzr server

Tags: bazaar

I have forgot the name of a branch of bzr, Is there any way to get the names of all branches on a bzr server

**UPDATE:** Forexample path to a branch on bzr server is:

```
bzr+ssh://bzr@192.168.7.171/~/branches/proj_name
```

Now I want to get all the names of projects present on the server

I promise 300 points bounty, once it is available on this question. Please help

Comment: I promise 300 points bounty, once it is available on this question. Please help

Comment: What is the link with bzr-svn ?

Comment: Do you have access to the server to browse the repository with a file manager ?

Comment: @TridenT I have updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Bazaar Explorer**, go to **File > Open location** and write down your repository.

```
bzr://MyServer/path/to/MyRepo/
```

Then you will see all branches in this repository.

**EDIT.**

As an example, just browse emacs project : `bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs`
[image]

Comment: I want to view all the branch names on the server, while your solution works for a certain repo

Comment: Do you mean you want all branches for all projects inside all repositories served ?

Comment: Yes, I want to view all branches of all projects inside all repos

Comment: when I open url, the branch names are being shown but the error message also appears: "Unable to change to location /my/location/url_i_entered. Closing window". When I click ok, the branch names also disappear

Comment: I tested on different repositories with Bazaar 2.6b1, it works pretty well.